# Does the Software Center log installations?

Tags: software-center, re-installation

Does the Ubuntu Software Center keep a log of everything it has installed? So I could just parse this log to convert it into a script full of 'sudo apt-get instals' or something. And then the next time I install Ubuntu I could just this script to re-install everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It maintains a log in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. Older histories gets compressed as `.gz` files. It contains installation, upgrade and removal logs.
For keeping existing software backups you can use
`dpkg-repack` to make `.deb` files out of installed files. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=819396).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. You're looking for the file:

```
~/.cache/software-center/apthistory.p
```

I have no idea how to parse it or how to understand the format it's in, but that's not the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a list of all manually installed packages which are not a dependency of another package by running this command:

```
$ deborphan -a | awk '{print $2}' | sort > packages.list
```

For reinstalling these packages, use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install $(cat packages.list | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for personal use, there is a way to sync programs built in to the software center. If you just click File -> "Sync Between Computers". You just have to create an Ubuntu Software Center account. Here is a how-to with more information which may be relevant, http://www.howtogeek.com/111989/how-to-sync-quickly-reinstall-applications-on-ubuntu/.